# SQL COUNT one column of table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have simple script which count how many times users press search button
I'm trying to write down SQL command which count all querys for all users with one company. Below you see example of my table:

```
login | query | company
user1 |   40  |    1
user2 |   60  |    1
user3 |   30  |    2
```

So just for example I would like to write statment for how many querys all users from company 1 did, result should be number 100.

I try something like this but with no result:

```
public function getCompanyData()
{
    try{            
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        //$sql = "SELECT count(*) as total_count FROM users WHERE company = :company ";
        $sql = "SELECT company,SUN(query) as total_count FROM users GROUP BY company";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "company", $this->company, PDO::PARAM_STR );            
        $stmt->execute();
        if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this->count = $row['total_count'];
            echo $this->count;
            return $this->count;                
        }
    }catch( PDOException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

Is there a chance somebody can help me?
my own code throwing me error:
: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION MyDatabaseName.SUN does not exist

I'm not even sure if I'm doing it right so any help is welcome.

Thanks

EDIT: After uergen d help my function work, problem is that if i manualy count all query for company number 1, i get result around 1400, but script show me number around 300
Is there a chance somebody see something what i dont?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's

```
SUM(query)
```

not

```
SUN(query)
```

Comment: THUMBS UP! Thank you for this becuase i miss it :(, anyway my function throw me wrong number (it should say 1445, but it say 354, any idea?

Comment: I don't get it. Please update your question with additional examples.

Comment: I saw the update. But the query is fine. Anything special about the data?

Comment: I don't think so, if you want i can provide table dump, its just my localhost so nothing secret. But not sure if you have time for something like that.

Comment: You can build a quick [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and send me the link to it and I will have a look at it.

Comment: Yea, in the same time i found that i didn't add WHERE to my statment :(, this was stupid from me. 
Thanks for help